# How run test cafe studo tests from command line

Tags: testing, command-line, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Good day.
I want to run the test cafe studio tests from the command line because our CI(TFS) is not supported.
All the examples that I found are intended for the Old version of the test cafe or for the free version.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The open-source TestCafe version can run tests created via the TestCafe Studio in the same way as regular TestCafe test files, so you can use the following command to run tests:
`testcafe chrome ./tests/fixture-created-in-tc-studio.testcafe`

https://docs.devexpress.com/TestCafeStudio/400610/faq